# Convert enhanced for each loop to streams java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to convert code written in enhanced for each loop to streams in java.
Here is my traditional code

```
    List<OrderDetail> orderDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    if (arInvoiceOrderResponseBody != null) {
        if (arInvoiceOrderResponseBody.getOrders() != null && 
         arInvoiceOrderResponseBody.getOrders().size() > 0) {
         for (OrderDetail orderDetail : arInvoiceOrderResponseBody.getOrders()) {
                if (orderDetail != null) {
                    if (orderDetail.getStatusHistory() != null && 
                        orderDetail.getStatusHistory().size() > 0) {
                        for (StatusHistory statusHistory : orderDetail.getStatusHistory()) {
                            if (statusHistory != null) {
                                if (statusHistory.getStatusCode() != null) {
                                    if (statusHistory.getStatusCode().equals("POD")) {
                                        orderDetail.setStatusDateTime(statusHistory.getStatus_date_time());
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                orderDetails.add(orderDetail);
            }
            arInvoiceOrderResponseBody.setOrders(orderDetails);
        }
```

Can anyone help me on replicating same functionality through streams.Any help would be greatly helpful

This is what i am trying

```
    arInvoiceOrderResponseBody.getOrders().stream() .flatMap(order ->
    order.getStatusHistory().stream()) 
    .filter(statusHistory ->statusHistory.getStatusCode().equals("POD"))
    //Here if condition is true then i need to do this.I need to set one
    //of the property of main order object to one of the property of status 
    //history object 
    //order.setStatusDateTime(statusHistory.getStatus_date_time());
```

Comment: Edit it into your question, comments are not good for showing code

Comment: Edited in the question

Comment: I see. Yeah, this is not really appropriate problem to solve with streams, as shown by the problem you've run into. It's *possible*, but not with anything that's better than what you already have.

Comment: I am stuck while i am trying to get main order object again after filter because if condition is true then i need to set a property of main order object with the property of inner object status history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting it out into multiple methods and breaking it down into two streams may work. Something like:

```
  public static ResponseBody processResponseBody(ResponseBody responseBody)
  {
    if(validate(responseBody))
    {
      List<OrderDetail> orderDetails = responseBody.getOrders().stream()
          .filter(od -> validate(od))
          .map(od -> processOrderDetail(od))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
      responseBody.setOrders(orderDetails);
    }
    
    return responseBody;
  }
  
  private static OrderDetail processOrderDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
  {
    StatusHistory statusHistory = orderDetail.getStatusHistory().stream()
          .filter(sh -> validate(sh))
          .findFirst()
          .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No Status History Found"));
    orderDetail.setStatusDateTime(statusHistory.getStatus_date_time());

    return orderDetail;
  }
  
  private static boolean validate(ResponseBody responseBody)
  {
    return responseBody != null && responseBody.getOrders() != null && responseBody.getOrders().size() > 0;
  }
  
  private static boolean validate(OrderDetail orderDetail)
  {
    return orderDetail != null && orderDetail.getStatusHistory() != null && orderDetail.getStatusHistory().size() > 0;
  }
  
  private static boolean validate(StatusHistory statusHistory)
  {
    return statusHistory != null && statusHistory.getStatusCode() != null && statusHistory.getStatusCode().equals("POD");
  }
```

I broke it into a stream to process the `OrderDetail` object and a stream to reduce the `StatusHistory` to a single object. I also broke the validation into their own methods for brevity and organization.

Comment: Thank you.This helped me with validation also

Comment: Can you please help me if there is no POD status code then ho can i set orderDetail.setStatusDateTime(null);

Comment: I was able to do it by using Optional class is present.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Following is about as Java-8 as this is going to get in my opinion.

```java
arInvoiceOrderResponseBody.getOrders().forEach(
      orderDetail -> orderDetail.getStatusHistory().stream()
        .filter(statusHistory -> "POD".equals(statusHistory.getStatusCode()))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(statusHistory -> orderDetail.setStatusDateTime(statusHistory.getStatus_date_time()))
    );
```

I note the original code changes the existing `OrderDetail` instances but then puts them (all) into a new collection and replaces the original collection. This seems pointless on the face of it!

Comment: Yes because after modifying order detal object i need to send updated collection in response.So i am adding it to new collection and returning the new order detail collection